# Find the cosets of $\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}_2 $ in $ \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I know that $ (a,b), (c,d) $ are in the same coset iff $ (a, b) - (c,d)\in \{0\} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. So, in this case, $a = c $ and $b-d $ must be any even integer. May I say then there is a infinite number of cosets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. (The word "even" is unnecessary though.)

The cosets of $\{0\}\times\Bbb Z_2$ in $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z_2$ are of the form

$$\{x\}\times \Bbb Z_2$$

for each $x\in\Bbb Z$.